# sqlstm.sqpadto = sqlstm.sqadto causing segmentation fault

Tags: oracle, segmentation-fault, oracle-pro-c

When and how `sqlstm.sqpadto = sqlstm.sqadto`  can cause segmentation fault? I am getting segmentation fault and getting this line in the core file. I am using proC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core dumps are indicative of bugs somewhere along the line.  It might be due to incompatible versions of the software.  For instance, [this OTN forum message](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3255758#3255758) comes suggests that running a 9.2.0.6 version of the client against a 9.2.0.8 version of the server can cause the problem.

It is quite likely the problem is related to some combination of Oracle server version, Oracle client version, OS flavour and version, platform.  If such is the case it is also fairly likely that your problem will require a patch.  Do you have an Oracle Support account?

**edit**

Given that you have a support account I urge you to raise a Service Request at  [MyOracleSupport](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/ui/flash.html).  The SO community is fantastic when it comes to programming but you have a very esoteric problem which requires specialist knowledge.  Your organisation pays Oracle a lot of money for support, so it is sensible to take advantage of the facility.